# Devenv command line switches error

Tags: batch-file, visual-studio-2013, devenv

I have a simple solution which contains next to class projects also setup projects (extension installed in VS: vdproj).

Facing strange behaviour doing the following:

1. Open solution in VS2013  -> kick off rebuild -> no errors.
2. Create a small batch file:

   ```
   CALL "%VS120COMNTOOLS%vsvars32.bat"

   DEVENV "D:\Source\Solution.sln" /Rebuild "Debug|Any CPU" 1>NUL 2>&1

   IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO Error

   IF ERRORLEVEL 0 GOTO Yeah

   :Error
   COLOR c
   Echo.
   Echo end %date% - %time%
   Echo Failed!
   PAUSE

   :Yeah

   Echo.

   PAUSE
   ```
3. Run this batch file and the errorlevel is not zero
4. Changed now inside the batch file the devenv action to the following:

   ```
   DEVENV "D:\Source\Solution.sln" /Clean "Debug|Any CPU" 1>NUL 2>&1


   DEVENV "D:\Source\Solution.sln" /Build "Debug|Any CPU" 1>NUL 2>&1
   ```
5. Run this batch file and the errorlevel is zero

The strange thing is that without output redirection I do also not get any errors while running the batch with the rebuild action active.

Any suggestions why I do get a different behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

In the first case you are doing a Rebuild. In the second case you are doing a Clean and Build. Temporarily remove the 1>NUL 2>&1 and you should be able to see what the error is all about.

You might simplify things a bit and save the results like this. Then you can view the log file before you 'Press any key to continue' if you want.

```
CALL "%VS120COMNTOOLS%vsvars32.bat"
SET "LogFile=%Temp%\BuildLog.txt"
IF EXIST "%LogFile%" DEL /F /Q "%LogFile%"

DEVENV "D:\Source\Solution.sln" /Rebuild "Debug|Any CPU" 1>"%LogFile%" 2>&1
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (
   COLOR c
   Echo.
   Echo end %date% - %time%
   Echo Failed! View log file %LogFile% if you prefer. Then
)

PAUSE
IF EXIST "%LogFile%" DEL /F /Q "%LogFile%"
```

Comment: Already did the removal and there are absolutely no errors there displayed. That's why I am posting it here. Will update my question to highlight this.

Comment: ERROR LEVEL is probably just indicating that your command line is correct/incorrect and may not actually reflect the result of the build.

Comment: It's very poor form of any application to return errorlevel 0 when encountering an error while executing a command line given operation though.